# Integrate to find the RMS

Tags: integration

The current in an AC circuit is described by the formula:

$$ = 80 \cos(50\pi )$$

where $$ is the time in seconds. Calculate the root-mean-square value of the current between $ = 0$ and $ = 6$ milliseconds.

$$\text{RMS} = \sqrt{\frac{1}{b-a} \int_a^b y^2 \, dx}$$

So I find $y^2$ first

$$y^2  = 6400 \cos^2(50\pi t)$$

But no I dont know how to integrate $6400\cos^2(50\pi t)$

Can someone please tell me what method to use here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

$$\cos(2A)=2\cos^2(A)-1$$

Hence
$$\cos^2(A) = \frac12 \cdot\left( 1 + \cos(2A)\right)$$

Integrate
$$6400\cos^2(50\pi t)=3200(1+\cos(100\pi t))$$
instead.

Comment: Thanks, would I need to expand the brackets to do this?

Comment: $3200t + 10.185sin(100\pi t)$

Comment: looks fine to me.

Answer (score 1):

use that $$\cos(2x)=\cos(x)^2-\sin(x)^2=2\cos(x)^2-1$$